# writing tests for a post-self-insert-command hook

Tags: ert, self-insert-command

I wrote a minor mode with the purpose of modifying written text on the fly.

It is currently creating a `post-self-insert-command-hook`, and triggers only on specific keypresses (e.g. the space bar, a semicolon, an open parens).

As an example, the user would type `select` and when they press the space key, the buffer would now contain `SELECT`.

I'm having a hard time writing a test for this with ert. I've tried writing it thus:

```
(ert-deftest upcase-select ()
  (with-temp-buffer
    (sqlup-mode)
    (insert "select")
    (execute-kbd-macro (kbd "SPC"))
    (should (equal (buffer-string) "SELECT "))))
```

This test should verify that when I press the space key, the word `"select"` becomes the word `SELECT` But the test ends up comparing `" "` and `"SELECT "`.

How can I write a test that triggers the behavior I desire?

(and further: is this a terrible idea? what's a better idea?)

Comment: Not an answer, but it sounds like you're reimplementing abbrevs

Comment: I just took another look at this. It looks like `execute-kbd-macro` take pre- and post-command hooks into account. In other words, your code should work. Are you sure the underlying mode `sqlup-mode` work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [ecukes](https://github.com/ecukes/ecukes) to write these sorts of tests and it's *brilliant*.

Test cases look like [this](https://github.com/davidshepherd7/electric-operator/blob/master/features/python-mode.feature):

```
  # Check *args works ok
  Scenario: Space *args on its own
    When I type "f(*args)"
    Then I should see "f(*args)"

  Scenario: Space *args with other args
    When I type "f(a,*args)"
    Then I should see "f(a, *args)"

  # And **kwargs
  Scenario: Space **kwargs on its own
    When I type "f(**kwargs)"
    Then I should see "f(**kwargs)"

  Scenario: Space **kwargs with other args
    When I type "f(a,**kwargs)"
    Then I should see "f(a, **kwargs)"
```

I can add more details on setting it up if needed, or you can look at the project I linked (the `Cask` file and the `features` directory are relevant to ecukes).

Answer (score 3):

You can see how I solved a similar problem with [lispy-test.el](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy/blob/master/lispy-test.el).
Here's an example test:

```
(ert-deftest lispy-braces ()
  (should (string= (lispy-with "\"a regex \\\\|\"" "{")
                   "\"a regex \\\\{|\\\\}\""))
  (should (string= (lispy-with "\"a string |" "{")
                   "\"a string {|}")))
```

`lispy-with` is a macro that creates a temporary file with
`emacs-lisp-mode`, inserts the first string, calls the command
sequence decoded from the second string and returns the final buffer
contents:

```
(defmacro lispy-with (in &rest body)
  `(with-temp-buffer
     (emacs-lisp-mode)
     (lispy-mode)
     (insert ,in)
     (when (search-backward "~" nil t)
       (delete-char 1)
       (set-mark (point))
       (goto-char (point-max)))
     (search-backward "|")
     (delete-char 1)
     ,@(mapcar (lambda (x) (if (stringp x) `(lispy-unalias ,x) x)) body)
     (insert "|")
     (when (region-active-p)
       (exchange-point-and-mark)
       (insert "~"))
     (buffer-substring-no-properties
      (point-min)
      (point-max))))
```

Comment: So.. This simulates a self-insert-command ?

Comment: No, it resolves the command from the mode-map and calls it. Simulating stuff is kind of fragile. It's best to just call the command, bypassing all the interactive stuff.

Comment: And what's "lispy-unalias" ?

Comment: Just some function that looks up a key binding. See https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy/blob/master/lispy-test.el#L93

Answer (score 3):

My take on this is that `execute-kbd-macro` acts on the buffer of the *selected window* (it is effectively typed keystrokes from the user, after all), and you must therefore ensure that this is set to your temporary buffer.

e.g.:

```el
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert "select")
  (save-window-excursion
    (set-window-buffer nil (current-buffer))
    (execute-kbd-macro (kbd "SPC")))
  (buffer-string))
```

I note that the same kind of thing is going on in the code of Lindydancer's answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, the idea is great, you should write this kind of test cases for your packages.

One way to do this is to insert a suitable content into a temporary buffer, add suitable keys to the input queue, break into recursive edit, and let nature have its course. This way, things like post-command hooks are executed.

For example:

```
(defun test-upcase-interactively ()
  (let ((unread-command-events
         (append
          (kbd "M-u")
          ;; Remove the following line to stay in recursive edit.
          (kbd "C-M-c")          ; Exit recursive edit.
          unread-command-events)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (save-excursion
        (insert "words"))
      (save-window-excursion
        (select-window (display-buffer (current-buffer)))
        (recursive-edit))
      (buffer-substring (point-min) (point-max)))))



(ert-deftest my-test ()
  (should (equal (test-upcase-interactively)
           "WORDS")))
```

Of course, it's overkill to use the recursive edit trick for something like `upcase-word`, as it doesn't rely on pre- and post-commands.